# SQL left join twice from one table web2py

Tags: python, sql, web2py

How to do this thing?
I have two table

Table1:

```
-id
-table2_id_1
-table2_id_2
```

Table2:

```
-id
-table3_id
```

Table3:

```
-id 
-table4_id
-table5_id
-table6_id
```

Table4, Table5 and Table6:

```
-id
-name
-date
```

Main table is Table1

```
db(db.Table1).select()
```

I need to join twice Table2(colums) in witch i need to join Table3(in each table2_id_1 and table2_id_2 field table3_id is equals), than join Table4,Table5,Table6

Comment: Seems like you have 6 tables and not 2...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I really got, what you are trying to do, but if you just want to join the tables according to the id's, something like that should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON (a.table2_id_1 = b.id) JOIN
     table2 c ON (a.table2_id_2 = c.id) JOIN
     table3 d ON (b.table3_id = d.id) JOIN
     table3 e ON (c.table3_id = e.id) JOIN
     table4 f ON (d.table4_id = f.id) JOIN 
     table5 g ON (d.table5_id = g.id) JOIN
     table6 h ON (d.table6_id = h.id) JOIN
     table4 i ON (e.table4_id = i.id) JOIN 
     table5 j ON (e.table5_id = j.id) JOIN
     table6 k ON (e.table6_id = k.id)
```